# Custom event not instantiated

Tags: c#, events

**Updated:**
Apologies for the brevity, I knocked the example up quickly in the hope that it was something simple to determine.  I essentially have a component which inherits from a DataGridView:

```
public partial class MyGrid: DataGridView
{
    public MyGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public delegate void MyEventHandler(object myObject);

    public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        if (MyEvent != null)
        {
            object someObject = "[it varies what I supply here]";
            MyEvent(someObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Within my form I drag the component onto the form and wire up the event via the events window for MyGrid1 such that the form's designer class has this entry:

```
this.MyGrid1.MyEvent += new MyGrid.MyEventHandler(this.MyGrid1_MyEvent);
```

And within the form itself:

```
private void MyGrid1_MyEvent(object myObject)
{
    //do something....
}
```

But `MyEvent` is always `null` and as such the event never fires.

I'm pretty sure I've never had to instantiate MyEvent specifically before.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your code snipets are too short to tell you how to do it in your case, here is full example.

```
using System;
namespace MyCollections 
{
   using System.Collections;

   // A delegate type for hooking up change notifications.
   public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

   // A class that works just like ArrayList, but sends event
   // notifications whenever the list changes.
   public class ListWithChangedEvent: ArrayList 
   {
      // An event that clients can use to be notified whenever the
      // elements of the list change.
      public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;

      // Invoke the Changed event; called whenever list changes
      protected virtual void OnChanged(EventArgs e) 
      {
         if (Changed != null)
            Changed(this, e);
      }

      // Override some of the methods that can change the list;
      // invoke event after each
      public override int Add(object value) 
      {
         int i = base.Add(value);
         OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
         return i;
      }

      public override void Clear() 
      {
         base.Clear();
         OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
      }

      public override object this[int index] 
      {
         set 
         {
            base[index] = value;
            OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
         }
      }
   }
}

namespace TestEvents 
{
   using MyCollections;

   class EventListener 
   {
      private ListWithChangedEvent List;

      public EventListener(ListWithChangedEvent list) 
      {
         List = list;
         // Add "ListChanged" to the Changed event on "List".
         List.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler(ListChanged);
      }

      // This will be called whenever the list changes.
      private void ListChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
         Console.WriteLine("This is called when the event fires.");
      }

      public void Detach() 
      {
         // Detach the event and delete the list
         List.Changed -= new ChangedEventHandler(ListChanged);
         List = null;
      }
   }

   class Test 
   {
      // Test the ListWithChangedEvent class.
      public static void Main() 
      {
      // Create a new list.
      ListWithChangedEvent list = new ListWithChangedEvent();

      // Create a class that listens to the list's change event.
      EventListener listener = new EventListener(list);

      // Add and remove items from the list.
      list.Add("item 1");
      list.Clear();
      listener.Detach();
      }
   }
}
```

This is the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx). IF something is not clear you can read, they are more explanations.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I can explicitly assign the event handler rather than via the designer, it's just I've never had to do this before.

Answer (score 1):

You created your event handler, but you never attached any methods to it (as far as I can see from your code)
Try the following:

```
class test{
   Foo myobject = new Foo(); //since you didn't specify your class names
   myobject.MyEvent += myobject.MyEventHandler(method_to_call); 

   public void methodToCall(String s){
        //your logic on event trigger
   }
}
```